# Делаю телеграм бота и хочу чтобы он выводил имя пользователя и его отзыв в командную строку .Только ничего не выводиться

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Вот код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("мой токен")

@bot.message_handler(commands = ["reviews"])
def say2(message):
    re = bot.reply_to(message, "введите отзыв")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(re,num3)

def num3(message):
    nam3 = message.text

def get_name(message):
    user = bot.get_me()
    name = message.from_user.first_name
    print("имя нашего пользователя-",name,"а отзыв",nam3)
    
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Так в смысле, у вас же прокает `num3` в которой почти ничего не происходит, просто запихните все из `get_name` в `num3`. PS. А еще ваш `user` это не юзер, а бот

Comment: спасибо .Попробую